# Run an VAD(useing android studio) on mac with M1 chip but unable to run and it still needs HAXM emulator

Tags: android, apple-m1

I have tried three AVD with CPU/ABI arm64.
I think it should not need HAXM emulator to run.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go428.png)
But when i press the "run 'app'" button, it still says
"Intel Haxm is required to run this AVD. No emulator installed please download the emulator"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxC6B.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

In my case the read/write/execute permissions on the sdk folder (usually located at "/Users/${user_name}/Library/Android/sdk/") were not set correctly.